# Conditional Join Performance Optimization - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a need to look at a material object in our database, which can be any type of transaction my small construction firm deals with. Then, depending on the transaction type, figure out the due and promised dates. There are fifteen different transaction types, but I've mainly been concerned with four or five:

```
SELECT
    datatable.ID_Number,
    datatable.Object_Type,
    CASE
        WHEN Object_Type = 'AA' THEN (SELECT PO_DUE_DATE FROM tblPO WHERE datatable.ID_Number = tblPO.PO_ID)
        WHEN Object_Type = 'AB' THEN (SELECT PROD_DUE_DATE FROM tblPROD WHERE datatable.ID_Number = tblPROD.PROD_ID)
        WHEN Object_Type = 'AC' THEN (SELECT PLAN_DUE_DATE FROM tblPLAN WHERE datatable.ID_Number = tblPLAN.PLAN_ID)
        WHEN Object_Type = 'BN' THEN (SELECT NEED_DUE_DATE FROM tblPURCHASE WHERE datatable.ID_Number = tblPURCHASE.PURCHASE_ID)
    ELSE TO_DATE(NULL) END AS Object_Due_Date,
    CASE
        WHEN Object_Type = 'AA' THEN (SELECT PO_PROM_DATE FROM tblPO WHERE datatable.ID_Number = tblPO.PO_ID)
        WHEN Object_Type = 'AB' THEN (SELECT PROD_PROM_DATE FROM tblPROD WHERE datatable.ID_Number = tblPROD.PROD_ID)
        WHEN Object_Type = 'AC' THEN (SELECT PLAN_PROM_DATE FROM tblPLAN WHERE datatable.ID_Number = tblPLAN.PLAN_ID)
        WHEN Object_Type = 'BN' THEN (SELECT NEED_PROM_DATE FROM tblPURCHASE WHERE datatable.ID_Number = tblPURCHASE.PURCHASE_ID)
    ELSE TO_DATE(NULL) END AS Object_Promised_Date

FROM
    datatable

WHERE
    ( other filtering criteria )
```

which gives me an output like:

```
| ID_Number | Object_Type | Object_Due_Date | Object_Promised_Date |
|:---------:|:-----------:|:---------------:|:--------------------:|
|     1     |      AA     |    11/26/2018   |      10/18/2018      |
|     2     |      AB     |    5/12/2018    |       3/31/2018      |
|     3     |      AA     |    6/15/2018    |       9/18/2018      |
|     4     |      AA     |    1/24/2018    |       10/2/2018      |
|     5     |      ZZ     |    10/27/2018   |       6/11/2018      |
|     7     |      BN     |    1/23/2018    |       7/2/2018       |
|     8     |      AC     |     4/3/2018    |       8/3/2018       |
|     9     |      BN     |    12/1/2018    |       8/16/2018      |
|     10    |      BN     |    1/10/2018    |       10/6/2018      |
```

And it works beautifully! The problem is that `datatable` is some ~20 Million records, and those dates can change, so I need to refresh the report every so often (once or twice a week). It takes between 8-9 hours to run and update since, for every record, I am conditionally joining to another table.

How can I improve the runtime efficiency of this query? I know I could left join to the tables, but I don't know how to fill a single column value with a date, depending on `Object_Type`, vs having n-columns for `Type_AA_Due_Date` `Type_AB_ Due_Date` etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT
  dt.ID_Number,
  dt.Object_Type,
  CASE
    WHEN Object_Type = 'AA' THEN po.PO_DUE_DATE
    WHEN Object_Type = 'AB' THEN pd.PROD_DUE_DATE
    WHEN Object_Type = 'AC' THEN pl.PLAN_DUE_DATE
    WHEN Object_Type = 'BN' THEN pc.NEED_DUE_DATE
  ELSE TO_DATE(NULL) END AS Object_Due_Date,
  CASE
    WHEN Object_Type = 'AA' THEN po.PO_PROM_DATE
    WHEN Object_Type = 'AB' THEN pd.PROD_PROM_DATE
    WHEN Object_Type = 'AC' THEN pl.PLAN_PROM_DATE
    WHEN Object_Type = 'BN' THEN pc.NEED_PROM_DATE
  ELSE TO_DATE(NULL) END AS Object_Promised_Date
FROM
  datatable dt
LEFT JOIN tblPO po ON dt.ID_Number = po.PO_ID
LEFT JOIN tblPROD pd ON dt.ID_Number = pd.PROD_ID
LEFT JOIN tbdPLAN pl ON dt.ID_Number = pl.PLAN_ID
LEFT JOIN tblPURCHASE pc ON dt.ID_Number = pc.PURCHASE_ID
WHERE
    ( other filtering criteria )
```

I just replaced your conditional `SELECTs` with `LEFT JOINs`.  You could run an `EXPLAIN PLAN` on this vs. your original query and see if that changed anything.

**Other ideas**

- if you don't already have an index defined on `datatable.ID_Number` then you should create one on it, since it's accessed in all the `SELECTs` / `JOINs`
- possibly create indexes on your other `JOIN` columns (PO_ID, PROD_ID, ...) if they are not already indexed
- if you know rows will always exist in the `LEFT JOIN` tables, change the join to an `INNER JOIN`...that may speed it up

Comment: Would you be able to explain why this is a better solution?

Comment: I'd say it's normally better to have a "definite" join over a "conditional" join so the Optimizer can make a more accurate plan and doesn't have to guess.  That being said...you are the best judge :)  Try running both queries and an `EXPLAIN PLAN` as well to see if there is any difference / improvement.

Comment: Just for my curiosity were you able to test this out?  Was there any performance improvement?

Comment: I tested in terms of speed and it was way faster (9hrs -> 4 hrs), but I did not use `EXPLAIN PLAN` because I don't know how

Comment: Sweet!!  Just put the text `EXPLAIN PLAN` in front of your query (i.e. `EXPLAIN PLAN SELECT dt.ID_Number ... )` and run it.  That will give you the Optimizer's query plan.  You can compare it to the old query plan the same way and see what it's doing differently.  Maybe try fiddling with indexes to see if you can get it even faster!  Or maybe you can incorporate some of your `WHERE (other filtering criteria)` into your joins also.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try this approach:

```
SELECT
    datatable.ID_Number,
    datatable.Object_Type,
    COALESCE (tblPO.PO_DUE_DATE, tblPROD.PROD_DUE_DATE, tblPLAN.PLAN_DUE_DATE, 
              tblPURCHASE.NEED_DUE_DATE) AS Object_Due_Date,
    COALESCE (tblPO.PO_PROM_DATE, tblPROD.PROD_PROM_DATE, tblPLAN.PLAN_PROM_DATE,
              NEED_PROM_DATE.NEED_DUE_DATE) AS Object_Promised_Date
FROM
    datatable
    LEFT JOIN tblPO 
       ON  datatable.ID_Number = tblPO.PO_ID
       AND datatable.Object_Type = 'AA'
    LEFT JOIN tblPROD 
       ON  datatable.ID_Number = tblPROD.PROD_ID
       AND datatable.Object_Type = 'AB'
    LEFT JOIN tblPLAN 
       ON  datatable.ID_Number = tblPLAN.PLAN_ID
       AND datatable.Object_Type = 'AC'
    LEFT JOIN tblPURCHASE
       ON  datatable.ID_Number = tblPURCHASE.PURCHASE_ID
       AND datatable.Object_Type = 'BN'
WHERE
    ( other filtering criteria )
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN PO_DUE_DATE FROM tblPO` what do you mean by `from`  usually i use word join then on column names

Comment: That was a mistake - fixed

Comment: Tony, good approach. Oddly enough, `COALESCE` seems to yield me some really odd results, probably due to fields not being `NULL` but empty, filled with spaces or garbage byte data.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT
    datatable.ID_Number,
    datatable.Object_Type,
    tblPO.PO_DUE_DATE Object_Due_Date,
    tblPO.PO_PROM_DATE Object_Promised_Date
FROM
    datatable
join tblPO on  datatable.ID_Number = tblPO.PO_ID
WHERE
  Object_Type = 'AA' 
    ( other filtering criteria )

union all

SELECT
    datatable.ID_Number,
    datatable.Object_Type,
    tblPROD.PROD_DUE_DATE, 
    tblPROD.PROD_PROM_DATE 
FROM
    datatable
join tblPLAN on  datatable.ID_Number = tblPLAN.PLAN_ID
WHERE
  Object_Type = 'AB' 
    ( other filtering criteria )

union all 

as early with tables tblPLAN and  tblPURCHASE
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Needle's answer, but I like to combine similar data from different sources into a view. In this case I'm using an inline view, but if you're going to use it in a lot of places, it might be worth it to just create an actual view to just show the due and promised dates for different transaction types.

```
SELECT
    datatable.ID_Number,
    datatable.Object_Type,
    type_lookups.Object_Due_Date,
    type_lookups.Object_Promised_Date
FROM
    datatable
LEFT JOIN (
    select 'AA' as Object_Type,
        PO_DUE_DATE as Object_Due_Date,
        PO_PROM_DATE as Object_Promised_Date,
        PO_ID as ID
    from tblPO
    union all
    select 'AB' as Object_Type,
        PROD_DUE_DATE as Object_Due_Date,
        PROD_PROM_DATE as Object_Promised_Date,
        PROD_ID as ID
    from tblPROD 
    union all
    select 'AC' as Object_Type,
        PLAN_DUE_DATE as Object_Due_Date,
        PLAN_PROM_DATE as Object_Promised_Date,
        PLAN_ID as ID
    from tblPLAN
    union all
    select 'BN' as Object_Type,
        NEED_DUE_DATE as Object_Due_Date,
        NEED_PROM_DATE as Object_Promised_Date,
        PURCHASE_ID as ID
    from tblPURCHASE
    ) type_lookups
  ON type_lookups.object_type = datatable.Object_Type
  AND type_lookups.ID = datatable.ID_Number
WHERE
    ( other filtering criteria )
```

Comment: Could you add any explanation as to _why_ this outperforms my current approach?

Comment: Scalar subqueries (your current approach) get called once for each row; result caching will help if you have a low number of unique values, but generally if your query returns a lot of rows, I think you should try to move your logic into joins.